# Bug with comparison

Tags: javascript, comparison

I have this comparison

```
coordinats.start.i < 1 || coordinats.start.i > edge
```

Now I show outputs of this comparison.

[outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U3pE.png)

Everytime both of them have type String. 
Please, explaine me why I have this results?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking. Try providing a [mcve]. Try expressing the results in the form of text instead of a picture of text. Try explain what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of both variables is `String`, you need to parse them to `Integer`:

```
coordinats.start.i < 1 || parseInt(coordinats.start.i,10) > parseInt(edge,10)
```

Comment: No. This is pointless. Using a greater than or less than operator will cast a string to a number automatically.

Comment: Never use `parseInt` without a radix argument.

Comment: Аctually, it helped. Thank you.

Comment: > Using a greater than or less than operator will cast a string to a number automatically - only if one operand is a number. Otherwise they'll be compared as strings, char-by-char: '9' <= '12' => false

Comment: @Quentin I agree with the radix part.

Comment: No need to use parseInt in the first comparison; a < 1 always casts `a` to Number.